# pandas: to_csv with a numeric range of named columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible through pd.to_csv to provide a numeric range to the columns argument, even if the headers are labeled with strings?

Sample dataframe:

```
    January  February  March  April   May  June  July  August  September
0    67        43       48     58     82    102  118   114     82
1    45        27       16     12     65    89   112   100     35
```

If I wanted to write out the first eight columns, I would have to use:

```
pd.to_csv('<filename>',usecols=['January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August'])
```

This obviously takes up a lot of space, and is impractical with dataframes with over a hundred columns. But I can't seem to use a range of columns, or a slice, as an argument:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv',columns=list(range(1,9)))
```

This returns `KeyError: 'None of [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]] are in the [columns]'`.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do it, I just can't find any similar questions on SO...

Comment: Does `df.to_csv('filename.csv', usecols=df.columns[:8])` do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the names of the columns of the dataframe as a series and then slice that, eg:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', usecols=df.columns[:8])
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution:

```
df.ix[:, :7].to_csv('filename.csv')
```